# Localization in Class Library

Tags: c#, class, localization

I would like to localize my c# class library

The library will output a .dll file, which I will distribute to .net application bin folders.
I want localization in the class library but I do not want to have to recompile the DLL each time a localization change is required.

So ideally.... 
have c# class with resx files outside the assembly, so that when the contents of the resx changes, all that should be required is that the asp.net host application might require a restart.

Best case scenario, is that the asp.net host application doesn't require a restart.

Thanks in advance for your advice - the resx file will just hold string values.

If possible I would like to do this using a best practice method, or at least without writing a whole custom localization solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this stackoverflow question.

[Is there any performance difference in using .resx file and satellite assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145430/is-there-any-performance-difference-in-using-resx-file-and-satellite-assembly)

Looks like you can have a seperate resource dll.